# Making wide dataframe long but with swapped values within a pair in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c('2001-01-01',
                   '2001-01-02',
                   '2001-01-01',
                   '2001-01-02')),
  PID_A = c(1091, 1091, 1037, 1037),
  PID_B = c(2091, 2091, 2037, 2037),
  resp_A = c(3,1,2,4),
  resp_B = c(2,4,3,1),
  connect_A = c(6,2,5,3),
  connect_B = c(5,3,6,2)
)
```

I want to collapse across `_A`s and `_B`s to form one column for each variable. However, the `connect` column for each ID should be the values of its partner. For example, for the PID 1091's entry on 01-01-2001, the `resp` value for that row should be 3 (i.e. resp_A) and the `connect` value for that row should be 5 (i.e. connect_B, not connect_A).

Here is the desired output:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(rep(c('2001-01-01',
                       '2001-01-02'),4)),
  PID = c(1091, 1091, 2091, 2091, 1037, 1037, 2037, 2037),
  resp = c(3,1,2,4,2,4,3,1),
  connect = c(5,3,6,2,6,2,5,3)
)
```

Does anyone know an efficient way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to rename your columns before pivoting to long:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)

example |> 
  rename(connect_A = connect_B, connect_B = connect_A) |> 
  pivot_longer(-date, names_to = c(".value", "who"), names_sep = "_")
#> # A tibble: 8 × 5
#>   date       who     PID  resp connect
#>   <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 2001-01-01 A      1091     3       5
#> 2 2001-01-01 B      2091     2       6
#> 3 2001-01-02 A      1091     1       3
#> 4 2001-01-02 B      2091     4       2
#> 5 2001-01-01 A      1037     2       6
#> 6 2001-01-01 B      2037     3       5
#> 7 2001-01-02 A      1037     4       2
#> 8 2001-01-02 B      2037     1       3
```

Comment: Thanks @stefan! What if my variable names have multiple `_`s? For example, my variable names are `xxx_connect_A`, `xxx_connect_B`, `xxx_resp_A` and `xxx_resp_B`. How do I modify the code you've provided?